# Regex to get values after certain words

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I would like to get only the value after each AbcXXVal from the following text.

```
{ dnd{ Jddj} R{Jnd{8384}} AbcDeVal {83} AbcFgVal {991}}
```

The answer would be `83, 991`

I've tried to have a regex to use with `see` or `awk`

The regex I've tried so far to match only the values I want is this but is not correct.

```
Abc.*?Val {(.+)?}
```

Thanks for any help.

Regards

Comment: The regexp you show is a PCRE which is not supported by standard UNIX tools, nor is it supported by **any** version of awk or sed. [edit] your question to show the expected output given your posted sample input so we can help you (you haven't shown us if a "value" is `{83}` or `83` or something else, nor do I know if the values should appear all on one line or separate lines or something else). Also, are there always blanks before/after AbcXXVal or can you have `AbxXXVal{12}` or similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `awk` could you please try following once.

```
awk '
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if($i~/Abc[a-zA-Z]{2}Val/){
      gsub(/{|}/,"",$(i+1))
      val=(val?val OFS:"") $(i+1)
      i++
    }
  }
  print val
  val=""
}
'   Input_file
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. One question. In the real file, the string I show in my post is actually a field, and there are other fields that doesn't have `{ ` nor `}` and don't need to apply any parsing. Does your solution will still work in that case? I Mean field 1= abc, field2=xyz, field3=`the string I show in my original post`, field 4=fghd and the field separator is space.

Comment: My code is looking for matching string `Abc[a-aA-Z]{2}Val` next field of it. Even your next does not have `{` or `}` it should give you output. Please do let me know if you have any further queries.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go :
`Abc.*?Val\s*?{(\d*?)}`

This should have two groups that match the digits.
Example here: https://regex101.com/r/2l8eRu/1

Comment: That won't work in awk, sed or any other standard UNIX tool.